# How to print out this certain fibonacci sequence?

Tags: java, fibonacci

```
public static int getFib(int num) {

        if (num < 2) {
            return num;
        }
        return getFib(num - 1) + getFib(num - 2);
    }
```

How can I use this code to print out this sample output like file attached with the same format of print out

[image]

Comment: Maybe a `for` loop, call the code 20 times and print each result?

Comment: doesn't fibonacci start at 0?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It couldn't start at zero, because adding the number (0) to the implied previous (also 0) would just give a string of zeros.

Comment: check the picture i attached guys?

Comment: @AntonH It can start  at zero. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Comment: @AntonH i just googled it and the 0 is optional. you can add it but there is no need to

Comment: I edited my question. And it doesnt start at 0

Comment: Homework, haan??

Comment: @bub It can, but it's optional. I learned it as implied, so not added to the sequence.

Comment: Hello guys, Seems to be working fine except that it doesn't print the very last value. So for example Fib 20 prints up to 4181 but doesn't print the last value which is 6765. I tried all the methods suggested but the last value is not being printed. Anyone know?

Comment: I got that part working thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `getFib()` is like this:

```
public static int getFib(int num) {
        if (num < 2) {
            return num;
        }
        int tmp = getFib(num - 1) + getFib(num - 2);
        return tmp;
    }
```

In the `main()` function call the `getFib()` function for the asked number of times and print the values returned, as:

```
for(i=0;i<numberOfTimes;++i){
     System.out.println(getFib(i));
}
```

Comment: Hello, Seems to be working fine expcet that it doesnt print the very last value. So for example Fib 20 prints up to 4181 but doesnt print the last value which is 6765

Comment: Try "i<=numberOfTimes" in the "for" loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This stores your result and prints it out before continuing the calculation.

```
 public static int getFib(int num) {
        if (num < 2) {
            return num;
        }
        int tmp = getFib(num - 1) + getFib(num - 2);
        System.out.println(tmp);
        return tmp;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Seems to be working fine expcet that it doesnt print the very last value. So for example Fib 20 prints up to 4181 but doesnt print the last value which is 6765