# How to use printf to print out in a certain format

Tags: java, printing, printf

How do I use the command printf to print my output the same way in the attached output file?

[image: how to use printf to output in this format?]

this is my code currently:

```
else if (args[0].equals("fib")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (Integer.parseInt(args[1]) + 1); ++i) {
         System.out.println(getFib(i));
    }
}
```

How do i change it to make it print like the attached picture?
Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: this currently just prints out my values each on a separate line, I need it to print them like the same way in the attached picture

Comment: Hey man i dont see how i'm supposed to use that to make my output print out like my desired format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print out this certain fibonacci sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931865/how-to-print-out-this-certain-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: oh, it seems that that person has the same assignment however my question is how to use printf to make my output look like the attached picture output. Like I mean the format

Comment: I have the right result but i need it to print it the same way its printed in the attached picture

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

Instead of instant printing add all numbers into a list:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    numbers.add(fibonacci(i));
}
```

Then make a pattern for printf():

```
String pattern = "%" + (numbers.get(numbers.size()-1).toString().length() + 10) + "d";
```

where `(numbers.get(numbers.size()-1).toString().length() + 10)` is the sum of the number of characters in the largest number plus 10 spaces between columns.

Then print all elements of the list. The counter is needed in order to have no more than 6 columns:

```
int counter = 0;
        for (Integer integer : numbers) {
            if (counter == 6) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                counter = 0;
            }

            System.out.printf(pattern, integer);

            counter++;
        }
```